# How does ADFS keep a user authenticated?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-core, cookies, adfs

I'm using WsFed to implement ADFS SSO into an app. If I try to run `[Authorize]` methods, I'm taken to the sign in page. When I sign in, a cookie with encrypted information is created and I'm able to run `[Authorize]` methods. The cookie has option `ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);`. So far, this works as expected and an unauthorized user cannot access the app.

The confusion begins when the cookie expires, is altered, or deleted from the browser. When this happens, if I run an `[Authorized]` method I'm automatically signed in again without needing to reenter my credentials and the cookie is recreated. However, if I explicitly sign out using `return SignOut(...` method, then I am required to reenter my credentials.

Why does ADFS re-authenticate me if I delete the cookie, and how does it know to do so? It doesn't do it if I explicitly sign out. Shouldn't remaining authenticated depend on the cookie being present with the correct values?

Authentication setup in Startup.ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
{
    sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddWsFederation(options =>
{
    options.Wtrealm = Configuration["AppSettings:wsfed:realm"];
    options.MetadataAddress = Configuration["AppSettings:wsfed:metadata"];
    options.UseTokenLifetime = false;
})
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "AuthenticationCookie";
    options.LoginPath = "/signin-wsfed";
    options.LogoutPath = "/NameController/Logout";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

Login action:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Login()
{
    var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = "https://app:1234/NameController/Index",
    };

    return Challenge(authProperties, WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

Logout action:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult SignOutOfADFS()
{
    return SignOut(
        new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = "https://app:1234/NameController/AfterLogout"
        },
        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AD FS is an identity provider that is commonly used for single sign-on purposes. As part of that, a key feature is that the AD FS does remember the signed-in user in order to authenticate them for another website. It does that by remembering the user using a separate session persisted using a cookie for the AD FS website.

When you sign out locally from your application, then all you are doing is clearing your *local* cookie. So when you try to authenticate again and the user is challenged to authenticate with the identity provider, the AD FS is able to sign the user in without asking them again for their credentials. For the AD FS your application is then just like a third website which is asking for authentication after the user already signed in into the AD FS.

In order to sign out completely, you will have to do a WSFederation sign out. As part of that process, the local cookie is cleared and then the user is redirected to an AD FS signout page where the AD FS authentication cookie is also cleared. On a subsequent authentication attempt, the AD FS then cannot remember the user anymore (since there’s no cookie) so they have to authenticate again with their credentials. That is what you are doing in your `SignOutOfADFS` action.

The WSFederation protocol supports a way for the authenticating application to require the user to reauthenticate with the identity provider by passing the `wfresh=0` parameter with the authentication request. This is also supported in current AD FS versions. Unfortunately, I don’t think this parameter is currently supported by the WSFederation authentication handler for ASP.NET Core. It wouldn’t really prevent the user from reusing their authentication though, so you wouldn’t be able to use this a security feature.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. So, when I delete the `AuthenticationCookie` that is created by `.AddCookie()`, I am automatically authenticated again because a cookie for the AD FS website still has my information? And if I sign out using `SignOutOfADFS`, both the `AuthenticationCookie` and the cookie on AD FS website are deleted, and only then am I completely signed out?

Comment: Yeah, that’s right. When you delete the cookie on the application, the application triggers a sign-in and redirects to the ADFS which then still recognizes you and logs you back in without having you enter your credentials.

Comment: Do you happen to know for how long AD FS will still recognize me? And how could I modify that time?

Comment: I think you can configure that using the PowerShell cmdlet `Set-AdfsProperties -SsoLifetime`. You can surely also find some docs about “ADFS token lifetime”, e.g. [AD FS Single Sign-On Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/ad-fs-single-sign-on-settings)